# Running mule CE

Tags: mule, esb

I have downloaded mule standalone 3.6.1 from officiel site and unzip it then from bin I launched mule.

**Console:**

```
MULE_HOME is set to C:\mule-standalone-3.6.1
Running in console/foreground mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Starting the Mule Container...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library because none of the
          following files:
            wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll
            wrapper.dll
          could be located on the following java.library.path:
            C:\mule-standalone-3.6.1\bin\%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%
            C:\mule-standalone-3.6.1\lib\boot
          Please see the documentation for the wrapper.java.library.path
          configuration property.
          System signals will not be handled correctly.

INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,390 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.MuleContainer:
**********************************************************************
* Mule ESB and Integration Platform                                  *
* Version: 3.6.1 Build: b795785f                                     *
* MuleSoft, Inc.                                                     *
* For more information go to http://www.mulesoft.org                 *
*                                                                    *
* Server started: 29/03/15 23:34                                     *
* JDK: 1.8.0_40 (mixed mode)                                         *
* OS: Windows 7 - Service Pack 1 (6.1, amd64)                        *
* Host: Rajeun-PC (192.168.1.186)                                    *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,393 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager: Initializing core extension
s
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,394 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager: Starting core extensions
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,411 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ================== New Exploded Artifact: default
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,424 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.MuleSharedDomainClassLoader: Using domain dir C:\mule-standalone-3.6.1\dom
ains\default for domain default
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,533 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.MuleDeploymentService:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started domain 'default'                                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,540 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ================== New Exploded Artifact: default
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:32,560 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.application.DefaultMuleApplication:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'default'                                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:37,266 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.MuleDeploymentService:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'default'                                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:37,270 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-03-29 23:34:37,356 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
ncher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener:
**********************************************************************
*              - - + DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

********************************************************************************
***********************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -
 * - - + STATUS + - - *
********************************************************************************
***********************
* default                                       * default
 * DEPLOYED           *
********************************************************************************
***********************
```

Questions:

1. is every thing alright? is my server running well! how I can check it out.
2. if i would like to deploy my application is this the right way?

   - Navigate to the folder that contains your copy of Mule ESB Standalone, then paste the application’s zip file into the apps folder.

     - Mule polls the apps folder every 5 seconds (every 5000ms); it picks up the application you copied to the apps folder, then extracts and deploys it automatically. In the command line, Mule notifies you that it has deployed the application.
3. and then how I can access and test applications deployed on the server that I just installed.
4. is there a way to associate each action done in my code to graphique event so that the user of my application can visualize the operation of each step.
   for example i have created an application who sent an email to a device if it didn't receive a push. so can the user of my application see the progress of process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 3rd question :- "and then how I can access and test applications deployed on the server that I just installed." 
You can test the application in the same way you used to do in Mule/Anypoint studio.
For example, your application contains a http inbound endpoint... so to test the application you need to paste the url path in your browser and hit it .. once you do it, you can see your application working and producing the result you are expecting .
It is the same way you run and test your application in studio.

The answer of your 4rth question is you better use **log4j** in your application and **logger** at each steps in the flow...
so whenever the flow will run, you can see each step is logged in the standalone server console.
If you want to get more details of your steps, then configure your log4j in **DEBUG** mode

the 1st and 2nd question I guess is already answered

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes
2- Yes
3- Use the inbound endpoint of your application
4- Run the app in debug mode from AnyPointStudio

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes as it is showing *deployed* it means that you have deployed in right way.
2. Yes, everything looks good.

You can run the application in debug mode you can get more details.